# Android App, two Spinners onItemSelected

Tags: java, android

I have two spinners, one where you can select a time, one where you can select a date. So, i have two spinner onItemSelected methods, one for each spinner.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
THE_TIME=adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
filter_the_map(THE_TIME,THE_DAY);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
THE_DAY=adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
filter_the_map(THE_TIME,THE_DAY);
}
```

So, i have a map, and it has some markers on it,which all have days and times associated with them, i want to remove or add markers based on the Strings THE_TIME and THE_DAY. So, my first and smaller problem is, that when the app initializes, both onItemSelected are called(since something is selected from the very start), so the map gets filtered twice with the same condition. The more serious problem is, that when the app initializes, it needs to fetch the markers from the internet, and since the filters are also getting called as soon as the app starts, this could mean im filtering markers that are not even there yet. Seems like basic threading though im having some issues with them on mobile.

```
public void fetch_markers()
{
markers=get_them();
put_markers_on_map(markers);
}
```

If there is a better way to approach this or if u can help me with what i currently have it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve your problem you can set the first item in a spinner to be "Select Time" and in second one "Select Date" or anything else. As Spinners are not designed to be command widgets so one item in spinner is always selected. And in onItemSelected() method you can apply a check on the basis of name or position like:-

```
if(!adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select Date"))
{
THE_TIME=adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
filter_the_map(THE_TIME,THE_DAY);
}
```

Similarly, you can do for the second spinner.